# C# Json - JSONproperty of Various Data Types. .net 3.5

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-deserialization

Trying to figure out how to Serialize or Deserialize (JSON) an object, that has a value property that can be a bool, number, or string.

```
"object": {
  "id":"someID",
  "value": -10 or true or "someString"
}
```

I expect I will need to use JSONConvert, however I am not really finding how to do this with a Primitive DataType, all I can find is converting between a single object or an array of said object.  This seems like it should be straight forward, for whatever reason, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Just convert to object datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to object datatype, it can ben a number, string, list... You just have to handle it carefully.

```
    public class Object
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That is kind of what I came up with, I figured there might be a better way.  But I think I can run with this.